# emacs elisp (other-window 0)

Tags: emacs, hydra

I try to write a hydra function to switch  windows.
Basically I want that C-x o takes me to the other window, and then "o" will cycle through all the windows. So I put in .emacs

```
(global-set-key
   (kbd "C-x o")
   (defhydra hydra-other-window (:pre (other-window 1))
     "hydra other window"
     ("o" (other-window 1) "Next window")))
```

It does not work. `C-x o` does take me to the other window,
but press "o" does nothing.
However if I change 1 in the last line to 0,
it works as expected. It is quite surprising because
according the documentation, (other-window 0) will just
select in the current window. Is there a good explanation for this?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simpler code:

```cl
(defhydra hydra-other-window (global-map "C-x")
  "hydra other window"
  ("o" (other-window 1) "Next window"))
```

Comment: Will C-x 2 etc  work as usual after your modification?

Comment: I tested your code. It works great! Thanks a lot. Do you have idea why in my original code, the second "1" needs to be "0"?

Comment: Your original code calls `other-window` twice. You want to call it only once.